# How can I use Flask Admin panel in a different package?

Tags: python, flask

This is my application structure:

```
/blog
    /blog
        /app.py
         models.py
         views.py
        /admin
            __init__py
            views.py
            ...
```

I want to use flask-admin extension in a different package.

in `/admin/__init__.py` I imported the app and flask-admin extension:

```
from flask.ext.admin import Admin
from app import app
```

then I initiate the admin app like that:

```
admin = Admin(app)
```

However, I get 404 error. Why? Should I use blueprint or what?

Comment: You get a 404 on what?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're trying to hit the default `/admin` routes within your Flask app for Flask admin?

My guess right now is that none of your code does `import admin` anywhere, which is probably good since admin's `__init__.py` will try to re-import your app.py all over again (from the `from app import app` reference) and you'll end up in a circular dependency.

What I'd do is alter app.py to contain the `admin = Admin(app)` and `from flask.ext.admin import Admin` code, and also do a `from admin import views` and empty out the `admin/__init__.py` file completely.